# Local notifications implementation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, localnotification

I'm trying to implement Local notifications(with click events and HeadUP Notifications) for my android application using Xamarin.Forms. I've followed [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications) for Local Notifications but I don't know how to implement this.Can anyone please share any working sample for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Here is a official sampe.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LocalNotifications/

Answer (score 0):

From [Android official document](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java) ,there are two ways to set importance level.

[image]

**First Solution:** (Not Work)

If a notification's priority is flagged as High, Max, or full-screen, it gets a heads-up notification.

Examples of conditions that may trigger heads-up notifications include:
The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations.Using physical device to have a try as follow:

```
builder.SetVibrate(new long[0]);
builder.SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);
```

Here is a similar discussion about [Heads-up notification.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44486/how-can-i-get-notification-heads-up-working-with-setpriority)

> Unfortunately, the above solution does not work.

**Second Solution:**(Work)

The correct way in Xamarin Android can set property of **Channel** .If channel created by `NotificationImportance.High`,then can show heads-up.You can refer to [this official sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LocalNotifications/).And Modify your `CreateNotificationChannel` method as follow:

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
        var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
        //Replace follow NotificationImportance.Default to NotificationImportance.High
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.High)
        {
            Description = description
        };



        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

[image]
[image]